# Porqué mi depurador de VS code no se detiene en los puntos de interrupción?

Tags: php, laravel, vscode, xdebug

No sé si me falta hacer algo, pero he visto muchos tutoriales en internet y he hecho todos los pasos.
Fuí al wizard de Xdebug, pegué ahí toda la salida de mi phpinfo() y obtuve el binario para mi sistema operativo. Lo pegué en la carpeta ext de mi php (xampp/php/ext/), luego en VS code instalé la extensión PHP debug.
No sé porqué en éste punto me dicen (los tutoriales) que debo escoger en un select el lenguaje de programación a depurar. A mí no me sale éste select, pero creo que éste paso (si no me equivoco) es para hacer un archivo launch.json con la configuracion para depurar el lenguaje que yo seleccioné.
Ese archivo launch.json ya lo tenía con el siguiente contenido (lo dejo en una imagen):
[image: launch.json]

Y luego unas configuraciones en el php.ini. Tengo las siguientes

[image: php.ini]

Ésto es todo? Me falta algún paso?

Luego, donde está la flechita verde, en el select de al lado estoy seleccionando la condiguración que existe en el archivo launch.json que en mi caso se llama Laravel Debug Config Yohanna.

Creé un pequeño script con un simple for que recorriera un array para probar el depurador. Puedo marcar los puntos de interrupción, y al presionar F5 me salen los controles de depuración. Pero cuando voy a ejecutar el codigo en el navegador se supone que VS code debería tomar el control cuando la ejecución pase por el punto de interrupción, cierto? Pues no pasa nada. El código se ejecuta como si nada. Tampoco se me habilitan los botones de "step over", "step forward" etc..
Dejaré una imagen para que vean como se queda
Ya no sé que otra fuente consultar, porfa les agradezco mucho la ayuda.

[image: El depurador no me habilita los botones de depuración]

Comment: Hola Yohanna ¿que versión de Xdebug estas usando? La configuración que compartis es para la `v2.x.x` pero la la `v3.x.x` es distinta. [Más info aquí](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=xdebug.php-debug)

Comment: ok ok. Estoy usando la version 3.2.2 de Xdebug. Entonces como la debo hacer?